# Nest.js/mongoose and TypeScript - error in Prop decorator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm implementing connection to Mongo database in my Nest.js application (with usage of `mongoose` and `@nestjs/mongoose` modules. I'm following instructions from [Nest.js docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb):

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  userName: string;

  @Prop()
  password: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

export type UserDocument = User & Document;
```

However above code results in TypeScript error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ required: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropOptions'.
  Type '{ required: true; }' is not assignable to type '"number"'.
```

How do I pass options to Prop decorator properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated [here](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/issues/752) you should use `@nestjs/mongoose` v7.2.3 (or later) :)